# WaveShare TFT 1.44 Buttons in /dev/input

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I have:

[image]

Which is absolutely ideal for the project i work on for my daughter.

[image]

The problem however is that the buttons on the board have separate /dev/input/eventX files.

[image]

Do you know if this can be 'mapped' somehow, so that there is only one file in /dev/input/ created for all of the buttons (like keyboard, mouse?).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself.

For a Waveshare 1.44" TFT HAT for PI ZERO, go through the steps below to create overlay in a single /dev/input/event0 file.

1. **sudo nano /boot/overlays/waveshare.dto**

> /dts-v1/;
>       /plugin/;
>       / {
>          compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";
>
> ```
>    fragment@0 {
>       target-path = "/";
>       __overlay__ {
>          keypad: waveshare_keys {
>             compatible = "gpio-keys";
>             #address-cells = <1>;
>             #size-cells = <0>;        autorepeat;
>             button@21 {
>                label = "ENTER";
>                linux,code = <28>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 21 1>;
>             };
>             button@20 {
>                label = "SPACE";
>                linux,code = <57>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 20 1>;
>             };
>             button@16 {
>                label = "ESCAPE";
>                linux,code = <1>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 16 1>;
>             };
>             button@6 {
>                label = "JOY UP";
>                linux,code = <103>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 6 1>;
>             };
>             button@19 {
>                label = "JOY DOWN";
>                linux,code = <108>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 19 1>;
>             };
>             button@5 {
>                label = "JOY UP";
>                linux,code = <105>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 5 1>;
>             };
>             button@26 {
>                label = "JOY UP";
>                linux,code = <106>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 26 1>;
>             };
>             button@13 {
>                label = "JOY UP";
>                linux,code = <28>;
>                gpios = <&gpio 13 1>;
>             };
>          };
>       };
>    };
> };
> ```

2. **sudo dtc -I dts -O dtb -o /boot/overlays/waveshare.dtbo /boot/overlays/waveshare.dto**
3. **sudo nano /boot/config.txt**

Add at the end of file:

**dtoverlay=waveshare**

3. Save
4. **sudo reboot**
5. **evtest**

   root@raspberrypi:/Dev/SIMPlot/Tama# evtest
   No device specified, trying to scan all of /dev/input/event*
   Available devices:
   /dev/input/event0:  waveshare_keys
   Select the device event number [0-0]: 0
   Input driver version is 1.0.1
   Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x1 product 0x1 version 0x100
   Input device name: "waveshare_keys"
   Supported events:
   Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
   Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
   Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
   Event code 28 (KEY_ENTER)
   Event code 57 (KEY_SPACE)
   Event code 103 (KEY_UP)
   Event code 105 (KEY_LEFT)
   Event code 106 (KEY_RIGHT)
   Event code 108 (KEY_DOWN)
   Key repeat handling:
   Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
   Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
     Value    250
   Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
     Value     33
   Properties:
   Testing ... (interrupt to exit)